# Wrap Long Text in AmCharts 4 Bullet Tooltip

Tags: javascript, typescript, amcharts, amcharts4

How do I wrap text in a Bullet Tooltip? The code below produces a very large tooltip box that goes off the screen when I have a comment field that can contain many characters (500+).

```
const xyBullet = xySeries.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
xyBullet.tooltipText = '[bold]Comments[/]: {Comments}';
```

In AmCharts 3, I used BalloonText and set maxWidth on the balloon. In order to try to replicate this approach in AmCharts 4, I tried using:

```
xyBullet.tooltip.maxWidth = 300;
```

But that did not work.

Comment: I was able to make the tooltip label wrapped using `adapter`, but it only worked for the 1st time. See my issue here: https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/1308. Hope we will see updates soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the label object from the series like this:

```
xySeries.tooltip.label.wrap = true;

// optional
xySeries.tooltip.label.width = 300;
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/5av8whb0/76/

**Related issue:** https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/1308